# How to clear session in main web application and virtual sub applications? (ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net, session, iis, logout, application-pool

Our web application `(asp.net 4.0)` has following structure on the `IIS (7.5 / 8.0)`

```
-MainWebApp (application pool: MainWebApp)
--VirtualWepApp1 (application pool: VirtualWepApp1)
--VirtualWepApp2 (application pool: VirtualWepApp2)
--VirtualWepApp3 (application pool: VirtualWepApp3)
```

The single login page is located in the `MainWebApp`. the user related data are stored in the session and recreated in the `VirtualWepApp1, VirtualWepApp2, VirtualWepApp3` based on the `HttpContext.Current.Profile.UserName` whenever user accesses assets (.net pages) under those virtual application. Problem we are facing that the user is not fully logged out from the system if he/she goes through the `MainWebApp/logout` page.

The work around I've done is:

```
- create logout page for every application with Session.Abandon() and System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
- the logout link goes to the VirtualWepApp3/logout
- from VirtualWepApp3/logout redirect to VirtualWepApp2/logout
- from VirtualWepApp2/logout redirect to VirtualWepApp1/logout
- from VirtualWepApp1/logout redirect to MainWebApp/logout
```

Other solution would be to put all applications under the same app pool, but this - due to some other coding difficulties - is no-no.

**Question**: is there easy way to clear session / logout user from all applications (main and virtual)?

--
**PS**. I've inherited the this structure/architecture of the virtual apps.

Comment: As I assumed it is not possible to clear the session in all application pools from one place. This is actually expected behavior. Main reason is the security - ability to modify state of application pool from other application pool would open gate for various attacks especially in the multi-tenant hosting environments.

Answer (score 0):

Application pool main goal is (among others) to isolate your application so a possible (recommended solution) would be to signal each application to perform the desired sign-out:

```
System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

How?

Create an [HTTP Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (guarantee security restricting it's access to the caller allowed hosts/ip or/and using an encrypted key on the request) that when called sign's out a user on the current application.

Then when on one of the applications you sign-out you can include a call (signal) for the remaining applications logout handler passing the user information (key, etc).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852942/how-do-you-programatically-end-a-session-in-asp-net) answer may also apply to your needs.